# Using filter with custom datatypes

Tags: haskell, filter

I have these datatypes:

```
data Command = Back Int | Front Val deriving (Show,Eq)
data Val = Val {first::Int, second::Int, third::Int} deriving (Show, Eq)
type Program = [Command]
```

I have this function:

```
foo :: Program -> Int
foo list = length (filter (==Front Val {first, second, third}) list)
```

The purpose is to find how many times a Front occurs USING FILTER ONLY, and foo gives compilation error. I am not sure how to represent the integer/val part of Front.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @WillemVanOnsem said in his answer, the approach you're using doesn't work. Try using `filter (\x -> case x of { Front _ -> True; Back _ -> False }) list`. You may be able to work out how this works from that alone, but if you need any more details:

- `\x -> case x of { Front _ -> True; Back _ -> False }` is a *lambda expression*. It defines an unnamed (or *anonymous*) function which takes one parameter, named `x`, and returns the value given by `case x of { Front _ -> True; Back _ -> False }`.
- `case x of { Front _ -> True; Back _ -> False }` does *pattern matching* on `x`. If `x` is of the form `Front _`, where `_` can be anything, then it returns `True`; otherwise it returns `False`. Normally this statement would be formatted like this:

```
case x of
    Front _ -> True
    Back _ -> False
```

But the compact syntax above is shorter and so works better in this case.

- The lambda expression above - which as discussed returns `True` when its argument is of the form `Front _` - is then passed to `filter` as its argument.

Answer (score 5):

You can not use an equality check `(==) :: Eq a => a -> a -> Bool` with variables like `first` and `second`, if these do not have a value. What you need here is *pattern matching*.

We can for example use list comprehension:

```
foo :: Program -> Int
foo list = length [ v | v@(Front _) <- list ]
```

There is no need to match the parameter with `Val {}`, or `Val _ _ _`, etc. since the only data constructor for the `Val` type is `Val`.

In case you think you will later add more data constructors, you can however add an extra subpattern:

```
foo :: Program -> Int
foo list = length [ v | v@(Front (Val {})) <- list ]
```

Or we can do the pattern matching in a function and use `filter :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [a]`, like:

```
foo :: Program -> Int
foo = length . filter f
    where f (Front _) = True
          f _ = False
```

or if we include the `Val` data constructor check:

```
foo :: Program -> Int
foo = length . filter f
    where f (Front (Val {})) = True
          f _ = False
```

Comment: The OP did specifically say he was required to use `filter`. But this is definitely how I would do it if I had to implement this in a program.